# iOS AFNetworking 2.0 umlaut error

Tags: json, api, ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using `AFNetworking 2.0` to send data to my API (json). Everything works fine except of sending data with german letters like `ä ü ö` .

Does anyone know what is the problem?. The problem is not the API because i did it in Android and it worked.

Here is my code:

```
  - (void)createItem:(MyItem*)newItem image:(UIImage*)image complete:(void (^)(NSInteger responsecode, NSString *hash, NSDictionary *reason))completeBlock {

    NSData *imageData = [NSData new];
    if(image != nil) {
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [parameters newItem.address forKey:@"address"];
    [parameters newItem.email forKey:@"email"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:postUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *hash = operation.responseString;
        completeBlock([operation.response statusCode], hash, nil);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completeBlock([operation.response statusCode], nil, nil);
    }];
    [op start];

}
```